# IF statement with Functions inside

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to make an excel document calculate the number of days between 2 dates OR the number of days between the current date and the first date.

I've tried doing the following:

```
IF(B1 "", =TODAY()-A1, B1-A1)
```

The error message I'm getting is that Excel thinks it's not supposed to be a function and to put ' in front of the =.

Comment: what is `B1 ""` in your first part of IF function? do you mean `B1=""`? Remove the `=` within your current formula by the way

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IF(B1="",TODAY(),B1)-A1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go for an example as you tried.

Formula Used in C2 and applied for all by Drop Down **(Ctrl + D)**

```
=IFERROR(IF(B2="",TODAY()-A2,B2-A2),"")
```

The `IFERROR` just used for in case any error cases

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

`=IF(A1="","Missing Starting Date",IF((IF(B1="",TODAY()-A1,B1-A1))<0,"End Date is smaller than Starting Date",IF(B1="",TODAY()-A1,B1-A1)))`

[image]